# Jersey, content gzip/deflate

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to understand how I can apply different interceptor based on Content-Encoding gzip|deflate and supply data according to Accept-Encoding. I was reading about gzip/deflate interceptors, but don't quite understand how that works.

```
public Response bigPayload( PayloadDto data ) {
   ...
   return Response.ok( BigDataDto ).build(); 
}
```

basically I would like to be able to accept gzip/deflate for the payload json and return gzip/deflate data if supported.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e6704

Comment: yes, I saw that, where does it say how make it header depended so different interceptor can be attached to a different content, as far as I concerned documentation is not complete for this topic nor clear.
Example will work.

Answer (score 2):

To use GZIP with Jersey on server side, first you should implement ReaderInterceptor and WriterInterceptor:

```
@Provider // This Annotation is IMPORTANT!
public class GZipInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor, WriterInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        List<String> header = context.getHeaders().get("Content-Encoding");
        // decompress gzip stream only
        if (header != null && header.contains("gzip")) 
            context.setInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(context.getInputStream()));
        return context.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        context.setOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(context.getOutputStream()));
        context.getHeaders().add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

then make sure this @Provider class in under the auto-scan package/sub-package which configured by web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>your.provider.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

If you want to use gzip compression on demand, probably you can use a ThreadLocal variable for help, details please check my post [here](http://nick.rndesign.us/gzipinterceptor-for-jersey-service/).

Comment: very useful, thanks. There is a missing closing curly brace to close the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I you are looking to returned a zipped response from a user request when they have set the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` then you need to enable compression in the application server.

In Tomcat you need to change the `<TOMCAT_HOME>/conf/server.xml` as compression is turned off by default.

```
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" 
            port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            redirectPort="8443" 
            compression="on"
            compressionMinSize="1"
            noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
            compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain"/>
```

Note that you need to define the compressableMimeType's you want the app server to compress.

You can then test this with curl....

uncompressed content ...

```
curl http://localhost:8080/your/url/too/data
```

compressed content ...

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://localhost:8080/your/url/too/data
```